# Peer-to-peer chat not receiving/sending messages

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, p2p

I am trying to create peers that are connected to each other and are able to send/receive messages to everyone that they are connected to concurrently. They are all run on the same machine. Once connecting to a peer and acquiring a socket connection, I am starting two threads, one that is reading and one that is writing. However, `readLine()` blocks indefinitely and I am not sure where the problem exists. The peers successfully connect to each other, but the message exchange fails. Interrupting one peer causes a `"null"` message to be read from the other peers connected to it.

**EDIT**: Using `autoflush = true` in `PrintWriter` throws `"ConnectionReset"` exception to the other peers connected to the interrupted peer.

I have tried waiting for the reading thread to start before sending the message, getting the socket connection from either end of the peers, storing the input/output streams in lists stored as member variables and also just passing only the socket/all streams to each thread. Also tried different ways of reading, shown in comments in the reading thread.

```java
class ConnectionListener extends  Thread{

        public void run(){

            try {
                while (!allPeersJoined()) {

                    Socket socket = null;
                    socket = peerServer.accept();



                    new PeerReader(socket).start();
                    new PeerWriter(socket).start();
                }

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

```
    class PeerWriter extends Thread{


        PrintWriter writer;

        public PeerWriter(Socket socket){
            try {
                this.writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writer.println("Hello");
        }


    }

    class PeerReader extends Thread{

        BufferedReader reader;

        public PeerReader(Socket socket){
            try {
                this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String input = "";


            System.out.println("Waiting to receive messages...");
            try {


                System.out.println(reader.readLine());


//                while((input = reader.readLine()) != null){
//                    System.out.println(input);
//                }

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: Adding socket creation

```java
Thread t = new ConnectionListener();
t.start();

// Connect to all peers
for (String peer : peers) {
    new Socket("127.0.0.1", Integer.valueOf(peer));
}
```

Comment: Can we get the creation of the socket and the way the server read and send message ? Did you tried using flush() right after the writter ?

Comment: Added socket creation. I tried using flush which causes the same exception ( same behaviour as autoFlush = true in PrintWriter constructor ). Read/send messages are done in the 2 threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple socket but then never use them.

Right now the ConnectionListener get your connection, send the bytes on the connected sockets, but the sockets never responds ... because you never told them to.

You should in the same way you did with ConnectionListener, create an object called 
ClientConnection, that has its own writer and reader.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that. I create 2 other threads, one for reading and the other for writing, passing the socket to those and creating readers and writers. There I tell them to read and write respectively.

Comment: for (String peer : peers) {
    new Socket("127.0.0.1", Integer.valueOf(peer));
}
Those socket are connected to your ConnectionPeers, but does not send data.
The Reader/Writer Class is linked only in your server class "ConnectionListerner". So when one "client" (the plain socket) is connected, your server does sent the bytes in yours code, but your client socket doesn't do anything to read it. Same goes with printing, once a client socket is connected, it does nothing.

Comment: Sami Tahri is correct, and what you're saying is also correct but what you are doing is on the server-side to have something received you must first write on your client-side which is currently just a socket connection which is also never closed (which is what is causing the exception) you never write on this socket connection so no line will be ever read. Try creating a new PeerWriter for the client-side and also call socket.close()